# How to display labels from a pivoted dataframe in a scattered chart in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am new to the "visualization in Pandas" world and I am trying to visualize a set of data as a scattered chart.

Initially my `dataframe` looks like this:

```
country_code  'ABW'  'AFG'  'AGO' 'AIA'  'ALB'
0               0      0      0    43     106 
1               10     10     100  50     100
```

I transposed it and I have the following `dataframe df_transposed`:

```
                 kc0  kc1
 country_code
  'ABW'           0   10
  'AFG'           0   10
  'AGO'           0   100
  'AIA'          43   50
  'ALB'          106  100
```

I am now plotting this transposed `dataframe` into a beautiful chart that works fine, but I would like to have the `country_code` as a label on each point.

This is what I currently get by using:

```
df_transposed.plot.scatter(x='kc0', y='kc1')
```

[image]

Is it possible to add the country code as a label to all the dots in this chart?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this

```
data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
nd = data_df.shape[0]
with plt.style.context('seaborn'):      # 'fivethirtyeight'      
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8)) ;   
    for i in range(nd):
        x = data_df.loc[i,data_df.columns[1]]
        y = data_df.loc[i,data_df.columns[2]]
        tx= data_df.loc[i,data_df.columns[0]]
        plt.plot(x, y, marker='o',ms=29, c='orange',alpha = 0.6)
        plt.text(x,y, tx, fontsize=18)
    plt.title('Nobel Laureates vs Chocolate Consumption', fontweight='bold',fontsize=35)
    plt.margins(0.1)
    plt.show()
```

gives this:
[image]

Full example [here](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/gradient-descent-algorithm.html)